# Spring WS remove flexible URL, Restricting WSDL URL and service URL

Tags: soap, spring-boot, spring-ws

I'm trying to make a Spring Boot Soap WebService application, and was following the Get Started (https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) example to learn how to do this.

I've created what I want, but I have two URL problems with this setup and I could not find what configuration should I change to fix this :

- WSDL URL basic is localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl but anything like localhost:8080/ws/whatever/countries.wsdl is correct
- service URL for SoapUI request is localhost:8080/ws but anything like localhost:8080/ws/whatever is correct

I know that this is a feature for Spring WS, but I want a fixed URL (without 'whatever' in both cases) and could not find what to change for this

Comment: I think you question is good one. Upvoted :)

Comment: Can you review my changes in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight forward way to restrict the way you want.

1. SOAP service is not URL based.
2. SOAP message body describe the endpoint.

> The thing you wanted is possible following way.

### Changing URL mapping in `ServletRegistrationBean` to restrict URL access

1. Existing `/ws/*` mapping is the reason why all the `/ws/whatever` url successfully responded.
2. Change as `new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws");`
3. Effect will be you can not request other than `/ws` URL
4. Now the **problem** is, you can not get WSDL by this mapping.

### Solution to get WSDL

1. The `DefaultWsdl11Definition` is actually generating WSDL from XSD on every request.
2. Save `countries.wsdl` to `resource` folder as static WSDL file.
3. Remove `DefaultWsdl11Definition` bean.
4. Create a new `SimpleWsdl11Definition` bean as like

   `@Bean(name = "countries")
           public SimpleWsdl11Definition orders() {
               SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
               wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("countries.wsdl"));
               return wsdl11Definition;
           }`
5. Now add another static URL mapping in `ServletRegistrationBean`. As it will be finally look like `new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws", "/ws/countries.wsdl");`
6. This practice is good for development phase as you can publish easily the changed definition. But it is recommended to use `static-wsdl` for production environment. Details ** [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure)

Comment: I do not want to add 'whatever' to the URL, I want to disable the flexible URL setting.

Comment: So, now all of the following works : localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl  localhost:8080/ws/stuff/countries.wsdl  localhost:8080/ws/stuff2/countries.wsdl  ; I want only localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl to work, the rest to return error or be ignored

Comment: Please check my corrected answer. I think it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
```

for example to

```
return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, new String[]{
        "/ws/v1/countries.wsdl",
        "/ws/v2/countries.wsdl"
});
```